# How to get out of this do-while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I'm working on a project and have a similar loop to the one below where the user inputs several values in the format of a character followed by an integer. I would like to be able to exit this loop when the user simply enters the trailer value 'E'. Is it possible to get out of this loop by ONLY inputting an 'E' instead of an 'E' followed by an integer?

```
    int main()
{
    char letter;
    int charge;
    do
    {
        cout << "Input letter and charge: ";
        cin >> letter >> charge;
    }while(letter != 'E');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read the char first, check it, and then decide whether you need to read another integer or not?

Comment: @JoshChlan I'd encourage you to accept one of these answers, [aga_pan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2122675/aga-pan)'s or mine, if they helped you find your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a fan of `while(true)` when there actually is an exit condition so I'd do this:

```
int main()
{
    char letter = 'E';
    int charge;

    cout << "Input letter and charge: ";

    for(cin >> letter; letter != 'E'; cin >> letter)
    {
        cin >> charge;
        cout << "Input letter and charge: ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what happens when letter is randomly initialized to 'E'

Comment: @Adrian It should be initialized by the first `cin`.

Comment: @Adrian That doesn't make any sense, then variables in a `for` loop would be tested before they are intitialized! Search for: "The for loop" http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: I knew it was wrong but incorrect for the other reasons. Johnathan is correct. And I really hate this style - it is not normal try this `int main()
{
    char letter='E';
    int charge;

    cout << "Input letter and charge: ";

    for(cin >> letter; letter != 'E'; cin >> letter)
    {
        cin >> charge;
        cout << "Input letter and charge: ";
    }
    return 0;
}
` And enter junk so the read fails

Answer (score 5):

You can use break:

```
do
{
    cout << "Input letter and charge: ";
    cin >> letter;

    if (letter == 'E') break;

    cin >> charge;

} while (true);
```